# Separating bash script into subscripts when this code contains variable assignments, loops and input from stdin

Tags: bash, eval, variable-assignment

I am trying to break my script up into smaller parts to make it more organized and readable.

I would like to take some code (that contains a while loop, variable assignment and user input) and put this code into another file. Below is an example of my code. It performs exactly as it should.

**Script that works**

```
var1="hello"
var2="world"
echo "Defaults: Var1(a)-$var1 Var2(b)-$var2"
read -p "Change Defaults? ";
while [ $REPLY != "n" ]
do
        if [ $REPLY == "a" ]
        then
             read -p "Var1 = "
             var1=$REPLY
        elif [ $REPLY == "b" ]
        then
             read -p "Var2 = "
             var2=$REPLY
        fi
        read -p "Change Defaults? ";
done
echo "$var1 $var2"
```

I would like my script to perform the same but just look different and be structured differently

**What I would like the script to look like**

```
var1="hello"
var2="world"
echo "Defaults: Var1(a)-$var1 Var2(b)-$var2"
cmd=$(cat other_file.txt)
eval $cmd
echo "$var1 $var2"
```

Where other_file.txt contains

```
read -p "Change Defaults? ";
while [ $REPLY != "n" ]
do
        if [ $REPLY == "a" ]
        then
             read -p "Var1 = "
             var1=$REPLY
        elif [ $REPLY == "b" ]
        then 
             read -p "Var2 = "
             var2=$REPLY
        fi
        read -p "Change Defaults? ";
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.` (aka `source`) to import a function definition.

`other_file.bash` would contain (with a few improvements)

```
foo () {
    local REPLY
    read -p "Change Defaults? "
    while [[ $REPLY != n ]]
    do
        if [[ $REPLY == a ]]
        then
             read -p "Var1 = " var1
        elif [[ $REPLY == b ]]
        then 
             read -p "Var2 = " var2
        fi
        read -p "Change Defaults? "
    done
}
```

And in your script:

```
. otherfile.bash

var1="hello"
var2="world"
echo "Defaults: Var1(a)-$var1 Var2(b)-$var2"
foo
echo "$var1 $var2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with moving the common code in a function.
When the function is working fine, you can move it to an include file. I made up the name "include", since is looks like other languages.
An include file can be included by other files too, so be sure that you have tested your function well before "deploying" in into an include file.
The include file can be included by sourcing it (using `source includefile` of `. includefile`). You might want to set up one folder with only include files. I have a project with subdirs `bin`, `shlib`, `config` and `sql`. The `shlib` folder has all include files.
When you make a function, you can spend more time in what it can. I would change your changedefault loop with

```
changevars() {
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "${FUNCNAME} should be called with at least 1 argument"
      return
   fi
  PS3="Change Defaults (n to quit)?"
  select opt in "$@"
  do
     if [[ $REPLY = n ]]; then
        break;
     fi
     [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ $REPLY -le  $# ] &&
        read -p "$opt (${!opt}) = " ${opt}
   done
}
```

and call this function with

```
source yourpath/shlib/util.sh
var1="hello"
var2="world"
echo "Defaults: Var1(a)-$var1 Var2(b)-$var2"

changevars var1 var2

echo "$var1 $var2"
```